# How to have selectable images from image gallery in javafx?

Tags: image, select, javafx, gallery

I am making an image gallery. I am using javafx 8 along with scene builder for GUI. I want the user to have choice of selecting images from a gallery: I want to have clickable and selectable images in the gallery. I also want to note the sequence of those selected images, i.e. which one was selected first and which one was selected last. I have made the gallery but I was wondering what I would do to make the images clickable and get the images selected, noting their sequence? I don't want to use checkboxes with the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a setOnMouseClicked handler on each ImageView.

Here is a code example of what I mean:

```
public class ClickableImage extends Application {

    private ArrayList<String> clickedImages = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
        String imgUrl = getClass().getResource("image.png").toExternalForm();
        assert imgUrl != null;
        Image img = new Image(imgUrl);
        assert img != null;

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
        imgView.setUserData(imgUrl);
        root.setCenter(imgView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ClickableImage");
        primaryStage.show();

        //-------------

        imgView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            String clickedImgUrl = (String)((ImageView)e.getSource()).getUserData();
            System.out.println("Image was clicked: " + clickedImgUrl);
            clickedImages.add(clickedImgUrl);
        });                
    }
}
```

Comment: as I said I also want to note sequence of clicked images so how can I get clicked imageView while using setOnMouseClicked as imageView doesn't work with actionevent

Comment: I have to admit that I don't understand what your problem is. Once you have attached your handler to all your image views, this handler will be called each time when you click on an image. Now the easiest thing you could do is to get the source (ImageView) from the event object and from that you can get the contained image and you can then store that in an ArrayList for example. The content of this list then describes the sequence of you clicks. Is that what you want or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but setOnMouseClicked doesn't return the source. In given code extendedImage is my class which extends image class and adds one extra function of image id. The given code gives error as I cannot pass ActionEven image as argument and I cannot get the source,,,,,,,,
    public void setValue(ActionEvent image){
        clicks++;
        ImageView clickedImageView = (ImageView)image.getSource();
        extendedImage clickedImage = (extendedImage)clickedImageView.getImage();
        int imageId = clickedImage.getId();
        clickedImageId.add(imageId);
    }

Comment: I also would like to tell am using sceneBuilder and registering the event setOnMouseClicked there in code options of image view.

Comment: I have got that.. Your answer is ok. But I am using 35 imageViews in scenebuilder as I said in my original question that's a image gallery. Shall I have to make 35 FXML imageViews in controller and associate each one with each one in scenebuilder. And shall I have to write this setOnMouseClicked function 35 times ??

Comment: If you want to see 35 images at the same time then you will have to create 35 image views and populate them with a corresponding image. In such cases it may be easier to do that in code and not in SceneBuilder. You can put the handler code into a function and reuse that for all image views but of course you have to set the handler on every single image view.